# How can I search for an XML tag in the response of a Rails controller with RSpec 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

We're working on a controller. It looks a bit like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :xml

  def show
    respond_with(Article.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

We'd like to expect that a certain field shows up in the result.  We tried doing this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ArticlesController do
  describe "#show" do
    let(:article) { Article.create!(:title => "3,527 can't-fail tips to improve your clickthrough rates.") }
    subject { get :show, :id => article.id; response }
    it { should have_selector("title", :text => "3,527 can't-fail tips to improve your clickthrough rates.") }
  end
end
```

but got this:

```
Failures:

  1) ArticlesController#show 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector("title", :text => "3,527 can't-fail tips to improve your clickthrough rates.") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_content?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000100e29770>
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So `have_selector` isn't right.  And `have_tag` doesn't work either.  What's the right way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

it { should have_selector("title", :content => "3,527 can't-fail tips to improve your clickthrough rates.") }

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo.  I meant `have_selector`.  Just verified that that gives me a `NoMethodError` too.  I've updated the question.